# Referencing a .env variable inside package.json with cross-env package

Tags: reactjs, npm, environment-variables, package.json, cross-env

I want to define an url inside a `.env` file and then use it inside package.json using the [cross-env package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env):

```
# .env
REACT_APP_TESET_URL=https://test.com
```

```
// package.json
{
  //...
  "scripts": {
    "start": "rescripts start"
    "start:test": "cross-env REACT_APP_MANUAL_URL=$REACT_APP_TEST_URL yarn start",
  }
}
```

but `$REACT_APP_TEST_URL` gets interpreted as a string.

I could of course pass in a `REACT_APP_ENV_NAME` variable via `cross-env` and then decide which `.env` variable to use with a `switch` statement inside my React app, but I would prefer to do it the way I described above.

is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: maybe you could create another .env file with say `.env.manual` your necessary data and then reference that in your command like `env-cmd -f .env.manual yarn start`? here is [env-cmd](https://www.npmjs.com/package/env-cmd)